# Why unsubscribed Application token can be used to access WSO2 APIM endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

There is an API hosted in `WSO2 APIM 4.1.0` and there are two different App subscribed to that API.

**Before Unsubscribe:**

[image: Subscription]

I just unsubscribed one of App to delete the API subscription by follows [wso2 doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-subscription/subscribe-to-an-api/)

**After Unsubscribe:**

[image: Unsubscribed]

After **unsubscribed** , I can able to invoke WSO2 API by using unsubscribed Application token

It should now allow that unsubscribed app to invoke API. `OR` correct me if my understanding is wrong.

**Postman :**

[image: postman]

Note: In above API Hit, I passed unsubscribed APP token as Authorization

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should not be able to invoke the API without a proper subscriptions. Although the token is valid, you should get a 403 HTTP code saying subscription validation has failed.

You can check whether the events are propagated successfully to your gateway node from the control plane node. This is basically when you have a distributed setup. If you have a HA setup, verify both nodes are working properly when it comes to event distribution.

Comment: Hi @Pubci
Thanks for response. I am running WSO2 APIM in standalone server (locally running), there is no cluster setup. please suggest some other way if possible

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the GA release of APIM 4.1.0? If so, this could be a bug in that was fixed later through U2 updates. When an application subscription is deleted, any API invocations done using the tokens of that application should fail due subscription validation with an error similar to the one below with a 403 HTTP code.

```
{"code":"900908","message":"Resource forbidden ","description":"User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed."}
```

If you have a paid WSO2 subsciption, please try this scenario by taking the latest U2 updated/patched version of APIM 4.1.0 by referring [this](https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/overview/).

Comment: Hi @RrR-,
Thanks for response., I have downloaded WSO2 APIm from WSO2 Website, I don't have WSO2 subscription. is there any other way to resolve this via Open source update?

Comment: Are you using apikey? Or is it the bearer token?

Comment: Hi @RrR-
I am passing OAuth token of Unsubscribed app as Authorization bearer value.

Comment: I tried the GA APIM 4.1.0 and this usecase worked as expected. Have you done any customisations?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the GA APIM 4.1.0 and this usecase worked as expected. Shall we verify the subscription delete event flow in the API gateway by enabling debug logs for gateway and keymanagement components?

Add the following configurations in the <APIM_HOME>/repository/logs/log4j2.properties

```
logger.gateway-component.name = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway
logger.gateway-component.level = DEBUG

logger.keymgt-component.name = org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt
logger.keymgt-component.level = DEBUG
```

make sure to add the newly created loggers as below.

```
loggers =  gateway-component,keymgt-component, AUDIT_LOG, trace-messages, org-apache-coyote, ....
```

With these, subscribe and unsubscribe events should be displayed in the terminal. You can use them to verify the event flow.